# pg_dump toc.dat missing public schema line

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, pg-dump, postgresql-11, pg-restore

I'm trying to parse the toc.dat file and I see different result when dumping same database from different pg_dump versions. On `9.6` I've got line with `SCHEMA public postgres` but I don't have this line from `11` `pg_dump`.

Anyone knows why's that? Can't find any release notes on that behaviour:

```
postgres db ~ $ /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_dump --format=custom -d db -p 5432 --schema-only -f /tmp/test-11-dump
postgres db ~ $ pg_restore -l -v /tmp/test-11-dump | grep "SCHEMA public" -A 1 -B 1
;   depends on: 205
22859; 0 0 ACL - SCHEMA public postgres
;   depends on: 74                           <--- no line with this id

postgres db ~ $ /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/pg_dump --format=custom -d db -p 5432 --schema-only -f /tmp/test-96-dump
postgres db ~ $ pg_restore -l -v /tmp/test-96-dump | grep "SCHEMA public" -A 1 -B 1
74; 2615 2200 SCHEMA - public postgres       <--- this line is missing from prev one
22832; 0 0 COMMENT - SCHEMA public postgres
;   depends on: 74
22833; 0 0 ACL - SCHEMA public postgres
;   depends on: 74

postgres db ~ $ pg_restore --version
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 11.15 (Ubuntu 11.15-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this commit [pg_dump](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=5955d934194c3888f30318209ade71b53d29777f) the relevant part being:

> This has the visible effect that the public schema won't be mentioned in the output at all, except for updating its ACL if it has a non-default ACL.